# Samba port 445 is listening but nmap reports that it's closed

Tags: networking, windows-10, samba

I have three computers on my local network: A and B with Windows 10 1803 installed on them and C with Ubuntu installed. Computer A can see the network shares on B, but B can't see any shares on A.

I am using computer C for checking for open ports with `nmap` and testing Samba with `smbclient`. I have verified that A is listening on port 445 by running `netstat -ab` on it, but when I try to check that port from C with `nmap <ip address of A> -p 445` it says that the port is closed. The firewall is disabled on A, and I've also disabled 'Filtering Platform Packet Drop,' but I still can't access port 445 of computer A from other devices on my network.

I've read about a virus called `Win32/Adylkuzz.B` that might be causing this, but I didn't see any traces of it.

Also I have enabled the old SMBv1 in the 'Turn Windows Features On or Off' dialog on both A and B.

How is it possible that Windows says that it's listening on a port, but it can't be accessed from any other device on the network even with the firewall turned off? What else could cause Samba to not work properly?